# Using Shockwave Flash as OCX control in Win32 app

Tags: flash, delphi

I program in Delphi.  On my development machine I have imported the Flash10h.ocx control and have developed a Win32 application which will render a swf file.  This all works fine on my development machine.

However, I am trying to get the same application to work on another box.  I have installed Flash for Internet Explorer; I can go to sites and it will place Flash.  But for some reason or another my Win32 application will not play the swf file.

One thing I have noticed is that on my development computer I have the following files in the **C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash** folder:

```
    Flash10h.ocx
    FlashInstall.log
    flashplayer.xpt
    FlashUtil10h_ActiveX.dll
    FlashUtil10h_ActiveX.exe
    FlashUtil10h_Plugin.exe
    install.log
    NPSWF32.dll
```

On the computer having problems I have the following:

```
    Flash10i.ocx
    FlashInstall.log
    flashplayer.xpt
    FlashUtil10h_Plugin.exe
    FlashUtil10i_ActiveX.dll
    FlashUtil10i_ActiveX.exe
    NPSWF32.dll
```

Any ideas why the Win32 app. is not playing the Flash Files?

Comment: My Bad - turns out that within my project I was making https calls to the server to get the data for the Flash.  The "other box" I was having problems on was this server.  And the way it was configured with DNS did not allow https to be called to itself.  Turns out not having anything to do with Flash but my http calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like a version mismatch. In your first list, look at the letter following the version number for both FlashUtil10_ActiveX.exe and FlashUtil10_Plugin.exe. On the working system, both files have  = 'h', which matches FlashUtil10h_ActiveX.dll; on the problem system, the FlashUtil10h_Plugin.exe doesn't match the  = "i" versions of FlashUtil10i_ActiveX.dll and .exe.

IOW, the parts just before the underscore in the filenames is a version number. On the good machine, all the version numbers match at 10**h**; on the bad machine, one file has version 10**h**, the other two are at version 10**i**.